# How to debug an issue deleting a directory using File.Delete and Directory.Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging

This one is proving very difficult to debug. Lets start with my situation:

I have an ASP.Net MVC3 web app developed with C# using .Net 4. Part of the system allows a user to upload a zip file. This is done fine, and the zip file is saved. There is also a Windows service which will periodically look for new zip files, extract them, do some work and then re-zip them back up. (I use `System.IO.Compression` for the zipping stuff). This part all works fine, after the processing I end up with a structure something like.

```
Object1Folder
 \_ Input.zip
 \_ ExtractedFolder
 \_ Output.zip
```

There is also a feature that allows the user to delete the item, and the requirement is to delete the object folder, in this case "Object1Folder". Because I need to delete all sub folders and files I have the following recursive function to do the work...

```
public static void DeleteDirectory(string directoryPath)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
    string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Delete(file);
    }

    foreach (string directory in directories)
    {
        DeleteDirectory(directory);
    }

    Directory.Delete(directoryPath, true);
}
```

Which is initially called something like...

```
DeleteDirectory("C:\\Objects\\Object1Folder");
```

But it doesn't work! Firstly, there is no error thrown, the code appears to successfully execute, which is annoying. But the result is that only the "Input.zip" file is removed. The "ExtractedFolder" and "Output.zip" file remains.

As far as I can tell, the code is sound. I can't see that it is a case that it doesn't attempt to delete the remaining file and folder. Unfortuantely, we don't have VS installed on the target server so I cannot step through the code and check that it attempts to delete them. Please point out if you can see this being a potential issue though?

My best guesses so far is that it is a permissions issue of some sort. What is interesting (perhaps) is that when I go to manual clean-up the problem (i.e. windows explorer delete of the "Object1Folder" it says "Denied" and asks me to confirm with the admin rights button thing that it does.

I know it's hard for you all to work the problem out, but I am looking for things that I should check to try and solve this problem. What kind of things should I ensure have correct permissions? What permissions do they need? Is there a good way for me to debug this issue? If something else has a hold of those files (maybe from the extraction process of the Windows Service), how can I check if this is the problem?

Some information about that server that might help: It's running "Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter" with service pack 1 and is 64-bit. The web app is assigned a user that is a member of both "Users" and "IIS_IUSRS".

Let me know if any of you need some extra information.

Comment: Have you tried running the solution / exe as Administrator (shift clicking when opening)

Comment: Nasty. I mean, not removing items - ok. Not throgin an exception or providing feedback - bad. Did you look at the event log? You should see failures there. Are the folder VISIBLE to the process=

Comment: @MikeyMouse: This is a web app so there is no exe to run

Comment: Make sure you don't swallow the exception somewhere.

Comment: @TomTom: No event errors, and none of the warnings and information appear to be related to the web app, let alone a specific file issue

Comment: @w0lf: I have checking the error handling code, there appears to me now swallow and I have made an explicit call to our logging functions to ensure the error is written if it occurs, but nothing gets logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the eventlog on the server; you might find an exception\error message there.

You could consider using `Directory.Delete(path, true)` so you delete the folder and all its content in one call (unless I do not understand your code correctly).

Have a look at files being in use. If a file is in use, the OS can't delete it. So make sure you are releasing all files correctly.

Finally, you can't force the files to be not in use so you might end up writing a clean script that runs every night to delete unwanted files and folders.

Comment: There are definitely no event log, I just re-tested and nothing was created. I think the original reason I have this code, is because a simple call to `Directory.Delete` wasn't working for me. I actually go this code from some other SO answers. Is there a tool I can use to check files in use? I have checked my code, and the other related bit to "output.zip" is a single call to the .Net zip function. Which doesn't appear to have any control on explicitly disposing of something it might be using.

Comment: Finally, I have thought about a clean up service but for me it's a very last resort. In fairness, I may add one in anyway just as a safe guard. But I don't want to be relying on it to do the required job.

Comment: Use http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 to determine what is using a file. Yes, clean up is a last resort but as far as I can see there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use a temp destination folder for your unpacked files.
When they have been used you can try deleting them and if that fails just leave them.
The permission to write to a non-temp folder should not really be given to a presentation app residing in the iis.